# Codility PermMissingElem gives strange results

Tags: java

The task is the following:

```
A zero-indexed array A consisting of N different integers is given. The array contains integers in the range [1..(N + 1)], which means that exactly one element is missing.
Your goal is to find that missing element.
Write a function:
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
that, given a zero-indexed array A, returns the value of the missing element.
For example, given array A such that:
  A[0] = 2
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 5
the function should return 4, as it is the missing element.
Assume that:
N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
the elements of A are all distinct;
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..(N + 1)].
Complexity:
expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
Elements of input arrays can be modified.
```

Now, my solution is the following:

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can use System.out.println for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        long nPlusOneSum = (A.length + 2) * (A.length + 1) / 2;
        long arraySum = 0;
        for (int element : A)
            arraySum += element;
        return (int)(nPlusOneSum - arraySum);
    }
}
```

the problem is that i have the following results:

[image]

I don't quite understand why I'm having those results in `large_range` and `large2` tests.

I made a sort of a test myself which should simulate large array:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeOtherTest {
    int[] maxArray;
    int N = 100000;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        maxArray = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxArray.length; i ++) {
            maxArray[i] = i + 1;
        }
        maxArray[0] = maxArray.length + 1;
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(solution(maxArray));

    }


    public int solution(int[] A) {
        long nPlusOneSum = (A.length + 2) * (A.length + 1) / 2;
        long arraySum = 0;
        for (int element : A)
            arraySum += element;
        return (int)(nPlusOneSum - arraySum);
    }
}
```

but it provides me the correct answer which is `1` (used jdk 1.8 something as in codility)

A link to the test results: https://codility.com/demo/results/demoWAS9FA-5FA/

**EDIT:**

this solution:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        long nPlusOneSum = (A.length + 2) * (A.length + 1) / 2;
        for (int element : A)
            nPlusOneSum -= element;
        return (int)nPlusOneSum;
    }
}
```

gives the same result: https://codility.com/demo/results/demoWAS9FA-5FA/

**EDIT2**

as soon as I introduced temporary variable to hold array length, test passed
code:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        long numberOfElementsPlusOne = A.length + 1;
        long nPlusOneSum = numberOfElementsPlusOne * (numberOfElementsPlusOne + 1) / 2;
        for (int element : A)
            nPlusOneSum -= element;
        return (int)nPlusOneSum;
    }
}
```

result: https://codility.com/demo/results/demoE82PUM-JCA/

**EDIT3**

the weird thing is that test still produces correct results, even despite that during it evaluation, overflow occurs.

`nPlusOneSum` gets overflowed and gets value `705182705` instead of `5000150001`.

`arraySum` doesn't get overflowed and gets value of `5000150000`

Then at return statement `nPlusOneSum - arraySum` is evaluated to `-4294967295` which for some reason is then by conversion to `(int)` gets the correct value `1`.

What happens exactly when operation overflows it's type in java?

Comment: Seems like Integer Overflow. Your return statement is casting the difference of two longs.

Comment: ye, but difference can't be bigger than 100.000.

Comment: same problem happen to me today and it looks below answer make sense.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is that `A.length` is integer. You should convert it to `long` before using.

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int element: A) {
        sum += element;
    }

    long expectedSum = (((long) A.length + 1) * ((long) A.length + 2)) / 2;

    return (int) (expectedSum - sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to java lang spec:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17

> The type of a multiplicative expression is the promoted type of its
>   operands

So resulting type of multiplication of two `int` is also an `int` which silently overflows for values around 100.000, the solution would be to change type of operands to long.

**EDIT**

the weird thing is that test still produces correct results, even despite that during it evaluation, overflow occurs.

Comment: Was curious about it so basically added a generalized [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868112/odd-behavior-creating-a-triangular-number/27868161#27868182) stating your problem

Answer (score 0):

There is small catch over here and Its:
Suppose length of your arrays is 100,000. You are trying to find the sum using the formula (N * (N+1))/2, that mean (100,000 * 100,101)/2. So here it multiplies both the numbers first which already exceeded the Max data type value. Hence you have seen the error.

```
  public int solution(int[] arr) {
    int realLen = arr.length + 1;
    long realSum = 0;
    if(realLen%2 == 0) {
        realSum = (realLen/2) * (realLen + 1);
    } else {
        realSum = realLen * ((realLen + 1)/2);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        realSum = realSum - arr[i];
    }

    return (int)realSum;
}
```