# Odd behavior creating a Triangular Number

Tags: java

The [Triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)  up to certain Nth has a known summation that converges to

`( n*(n+1) )/2`

Testing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    long solution = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
    System.out.println("Num: " + n + " Solution: " + solution);
}
```

Gives:

```
Num: 10 Solution: 55
```

If I increase the number to `100000`

```
int n = 100000;
long solution = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
System.out.println("Num: " + n + " Solution: " + solution);
```

Gives:

```
Num: 100000 Solution: 705082704
```

Which in fact should be:

```
Num: 100000 Solution: 5000050000
```

Changing the multiplication to:

```
long solution = n;
solution = (solution * (n+1))/2;
System.out.println("Num: " + n + " Solution: " + solution);
```

Seems to fix it, but why does `long solution = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;` fails to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are performing `int` arithmetic, which is overflowing before it can be converted to a `long`.  As you've noted, using a `long` for `n` in the first place forces `long` arithmetic.  As the math is done, values are promoted to `long`, where overflow won't take place here.

When using an `int` for `n`, the math is performed as `int`s before the result is cast to a `long` on the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be aware of the max value of an int which is approx 2E9, and that your calculation does:

```
1. (int * int) returns int
2. widening primitive conversion to long
```

Therefore your 1E5 * 1E5 = 1E10 overflows *before* the primitive conversion to a long. As [per the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1):

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format

Your expected result is just the actual result without the 33rd bit:

```
5,000,050,000 = 1 0010 1010 0000 0110 1011 0101 0101 0000
705,082,704   =   0010 1010 0000 0110 1011 0101 0101 0000
```

Using the long before starting your arithmetic avoids this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `long solution = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;`, the arithmetic is performed as `int` because `n` is an `int`, and finally the answer is casted to `long`.

What you want to do is cast `n` to `long` so that the arithmetic is performed as long, like this:

```
long solution = ((long)n * (n + 1)) / 2;
```